# Table view doesn't scroll when Reordering Rows/Cells beyond bounds of table using Three20

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, editing

When I re-order rows/cells in my Three20 TTTableViewController (editing a table and moving individual cells up or down) it does not scroll with the cell being moved beyond the bounds of the tableview. When I do drag the cell up beyond the bounds it automatically animates the cell upwards and out of the view without scrolling with it. This makes it impossible to effectively re-order cells to positions outside of what is currently visible.

I have tested this with and without Three20 and it only doesn't scroll the table when ordering with the Three20 implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Three20's `TTTableView` implementation overrides `UIScrollView`'s

`- (void)setContentSize:(CGSize)size;`

and

`- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)point;`

These are meant to prevent the contentOffset from being changed incorrectly with a change in content size or height of the table, although it inadvertently prevents the table from scrolling when moving rows in editing mode.

I commented out these methods and the functionality I needed became available.

Answer (score 1):

Three20 likes to control scrolling behavior with the setContentOffset and setContentSize method overrides. Scrolling behavior is controlled with a scrollEnabled property.

TTTableViews are scrollEnabled = YES, but at the time this method is called scrollEnabled = NO and needs to be reset when reordering rows.

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {
  tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
  }